# how to delete a bookmark completely if someone trys to modify bookmark text

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office

Hi I am trying to delete bookmark whenever I try to modify the "bookmark text"  **using "Word Application"**
I am adding a bookmark to document using belove given code snippet

```
Word.Document currDocument = WordApp.ActiveDocument;
Word.Selection currentSelection = WordApp.Selection;
if(currentSelection.HeaderFooter.IsHeader)
{
    Word.Range selectionRange = currentSelection.Range;
    selectionRange.Text ="ANYTEXT";
    currentDocument.Bookmarks.Add("bName", selectionRange);
}
```

Now whenever I try to edit the bookmark text (ANYTEXT) then, bookmark should be removed from that particular text.

Comment: You mean that when you try to modify text in a bookmark , new text won't replace the old one , instead they are concatenating?

Comment: I will be okay with either way, I will be blessed if I got the solution for both

Comment: From various comments I understand you want the bookmark to be removed when a *user* edits? Or should code be notified when the user edits so that code can do something? What, exactly, are you asking?

Comment: @CindyMeister I want to remove bookmark from that particular text

Comment: Yes, but under what conditions? What should trigger it? I get the feeling what you need is a `Content Control` rather than a bookmark. There's a setting for content controls that will remove them when text is typed in...

Comment: @CindyMeister   Can my code be notified when the user edits so that code can do something?

Comment: No, Word has no event for that. Which is why I suggested a content control.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below example

```
 _Application word = new Application();
Document doc = word.Documents.Open(@"D:\Documents\Bookmarked.dot");
doc.Bookmarks["mybookmark"].Select();
word.Selection.TypeText("Replacement text");
((_Application)word).Quit(WdSaveOptions.wdSaveChanges, WdOriginalFormat.wdOriginalDocumentFormat);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response,I need to edit the bookmark text on the word application, not from code, how can I get the control to my code on any modification made using word app to bookmark text?

Comment: I do not understand what  you mean, you create a bookmark in code and then you want to edit using word app?

Comment: We are inserting bookmark from code, but we don't want the user to edit that bookmark Text manually from word app. if he tries to edit bookmark Text we need to delete bookmark itself and convert the text into plain text.